# I am facing Lost Connection issue in android for flutter application

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am facing the issue of `Lost connection to device` in flutter application when it is tested in android application for certain number of actions, earlier it was not so, and the same actions when performed on an iOS device, everything works fine, how should I correct it. Is this the issue with the new Flutter upgrade? I have recently updated my flutter and I am using the firebase as a backend for the application

> Lost connection to device.

I am not adding any code because this issue happening with several components and if I add it will be too long, and I am sure this issue is with flutter upgradation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a lot of solutions for this but don't know what will work.

- Try by changing the USB
- Run `flutter clean`
- Restart the mobile
- Change the device you are working one
- Restart your PC